# Can Gentiles Work and Consume Pornography?

Tags: gentiles, sexuality

Would pornographic work be prohibited for Gentiles since casual relationships are not prohibited for them? And would anyone who consumes this being also a Gentile be prohibited since the wasting of seed is no longer prohibited as many Torah commentators advocate? In view of all this, both those who work in the pornographic industry and those who consume this product would not have any prohibition or would there be something more besides not being prohibited occasional relationships and waste of seed? And since pornography is sex for money it could be framed as prostitution and this is not forbidden to Gentiles, so this argument would not be valid either.

Comment: The question is probably not so much can they as, would they want to, realistically, given an honest self-appraisal of what they are doing for a living.

Comment: Honestly I think the analysis is correct, at least in technical terms -- as prostitution is not prohibited for non-Jews, it's hard to point to a source prohibiting, assuming no one is married. Someone could argue a "big picture" reason or "general good of society" reason or the like, I suppose.

Comment: The point is that the Torah works on top of technical laws and doesn't seem to address philosophical or spiritual issues, at least it's implied. The maximum that, in my opinion, could be prohibited would be child pornography, both for those who produce and for those who consume it, because the “law of the land” almost everywhere abhors it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why it would be prohibited for gentiles to traffic in adult pornography.  There are plenty of questionable things that are permitted to *Jews*. For the Ramban, “Be holy” means “Restrain yourself even with what is permitted.”  A holy person is one who is not self-indulgent:

> “You shall be holy” means “You should keep distant from sin and licentious behavior”.  The Torah prohibits certain sexual behaviors, and prohibits certain foods and drinks. But it permits sex between husband and wife, and [permits] the consumption of kosher meat and [kosher] wine. This might allow a person to act in a lewd manner with his wife [perhaps even in public], gorge himself with meat, inebriate himself with wine, and use vulgar language as much as he desires. The Torah does not forbid any of these things, and he would be allowed to be a vile, disgusting person with the Torah’s permission.

Comment: I see that by allowing certain practices Hashem was making concessions to men to be able to survive in the post garden of Eden world, just as the concession to eat meat when in the beginning only vegetables were allowed was a negative concession to our status before Him and the world, eat bread with the sweat of your brow. It is a very delicate issue as it involves more than one person and does not seem to contribute to the development of the man-Hashem relationship. But the Torah is naked and raw, it is either right or wrong, allowed or forbidden and that apparently is not forbidden.